# Javascript Date loop missing out Feb 2015

Tags: javascript, datetime

I am currently doing allot of work with js Date function - [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

I noticed when i was looping through Months that feb 2015 seems to be missing.

Im not entirely sure why, below is the code i'm running:

```
function test(){
    var current = new Date(Date.now())
    , start     = new Date(current.getFullYear(), current.getMonth() , 0)
    , end       = new Date();

    end.setMonth(start.getMonth() + 24);

    while(start < end){
        var year        = start.getFullYear()
        , month         = start.getMonth()
        , next          = "";

        document.write(month + "<br />");

        next = start.setMonth(start.getMonth() + 1);
        start = new Date(next);
    }

}

test();
```

and here is a jsfiddle i have set up http://jsfiddle.net/4bGmH/

Any help would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve but there is at least one major mistake: the argument to `Date.setMonth` must be an integer between 0 and 11. You cannot "roll over" months for a Date in JS.

Comment: this was just a test function i wrote to isolate the code. I need to list out all the months between two date points.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp, you can rollover using setMonth - it just treats it as [adding a year and the leftover months](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMonth)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because if you don't specify the date parameter for `setMonth` it uses the value from `getDate` ([see the docs](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.38)). You start out with a date value of 30 in your fiddle (due to using the "0" value when you create the date) so you miss out the shorter February month. The second February is only included because the `getDate` value is set to 1 when you skip the first February. Try:

```
next = start.setMonth(start.getMonth() + 1, 1);
// instead of 
next = start.setMonth(start.getMonth() + 1);
```

or

```
, start     = new Date(current.getFullYear(), current.getMonth() , 1)
// instead of
, start     = new Date(current.getFullYear(), current.getMonth() , 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Its happening because in your case month was starting by the date 30 as shown in below figure

[image]

So as we know feb contains 28 or 29 days so its skipping feb and by then the month starts from 2 of the month so in second case its printing feb as well

So write below code for answer :-

```
next = start.setMonth(start.getMonth() + 1, 1);
```